# How to get last item view from RecyclerView after adding new item and notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

Not able to get last item view after adding new item into adapter and **notifyDataSetChanged**.

Getting null item view when I am going to get last item view from RecyclerView after calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Following some scenario for getting item view object but not able to get exact view object but size and item count is correct.

**Scenario 1:**

```
mListItem.add("Hello Data");
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
View itemView= mRecyclerView.getChildAt(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

above **itemView** is always getting null value.

**Scenario 2:**

```
mListItem.add("Hello Data");
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
int lastItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
View itemView= linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastItemPosition);
```

above **itemView** giving second last item view but size is correct.

I am not able to understand why last item view is not available after calling right back **notifyDataSetChanged**.

Please explain!

Thanks!

Comment: i am guessing you want to scroll down to bottom after adding item in list , right?

Comment: @Quicklearner Yes, beacuse last item should be visible.

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: I have checked same behavior found.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

> ```
> mListItem.add("Hello Data");
> mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
> mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mListItem.size() - 1);
> ```

You should use list size like

`mListItem.size()` instead of `mAdapter.getItemCount()`

**And no need to call this**

```
View itemView= mRecyclerView.getChildAt(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Comment: mListItem.size() and mAdapter.getItemCount() both are giving same size. I need to call mRecyclerView.getChildAt(position) for view object

Comment: why do you  need to call this mRecyclerView.getChildAt(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1); ?

Comment: For getting last item view object so that I could update child view, because item view is like ViewGroup, it entail some view. I want to update view which is inside ViewGroup

Comment: just wondering if your recycler view has fixed height ,in scrollview ?

Comment: No there is no scroll view and not fixed height. Only I am using simple RecyclerView